# Star Trek TNG: Season 5, Episode 2, Darmok: Brass Solar System Artwork

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, art

[image][image: **Brass Solar System Artwork**]

In Star Trek TNG: Season 5, Episode 2, *Darmok* there is a brass Solar System artwork piece on the wall of the room that Troi and Data are in while trying to translate what the Tamarians are saying.

Who created this piece of artwok and are there reproductions available?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The piece in question is called *'Atomic Galaxy wall-hanging sculpture'*, an original artwork by [C Jeré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._Jer%C3%A9) that was [recently auctioned](https://www.artsy.net/artwork/c-jere-atomic-galaxy-wall-hanging-sculpture-los-angeles-ca). You can see the signature in the closeup.

[image]

[image]

It might interest you to note that it was displayed (in the show) upside-down.

---

Their work can be found in [several of the crew's quarters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL9qL.png). As a matter of interest, professional Star Trek memorabilia collector [zredthunder](https://www.yourprops.com/collector/zredthunder.html) was offered the piece prior to the set auction but declined it due to its size and expense.

> That is 100% a Jere’ piece of wall art. I had the opportunity to
>   purchase the original when I bought one of the three Datas room marble
>   based pieces with the chrome ball at the top also made by C. Jere’.

You can see [an earlier piece with a similar style](https://www.1stdibs.com/furniture/wall-decorations/wall-mounted-sculptures/atomic-galaxy-wall-sculpture-c-jere-circa-1965/id-f_3296382/) (by the same artists) below.

[image]

Comment: @MichaelE.Smith - I'm not *100% convinced* that it's the same piece. Some of the balls are missing from the auctioned one and it's got a ring that isn't on the one in the show. My (personal) guess is that it's the same and has been repaired at some point, but there's a possibility that it could be one of a sequence of semi-identical pieces.